# How can I use DolphinDB to replace NULL values of a column with linear interpolation?

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

I have a distributed table in single-value model with three columns: time, id and value. I want to input parameters including several ids and one timestamp. The value may be NULL at the given timestamp. If so, can I select the linear interpolation of the two nearest neighbors on the left or/and right side as the value at this timestamp? The search time span can also be taken into account as a parameter.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

set optional parameter type with three options “prev”, “next”, “linear”, default type= “prev”

default search_range = 1d

search_range can be 2d(#days), 7w(#weeks), 5M(#months), 1y(#years), no quotation marks needed

Syntax:

```py
geInterpolatedDataPoint(dbName, tblName, 2019.01.02T02:00:01.042, ids, "linear",2d)，geInterpolatedDataPoint(dbName, tblName, timestamp, ids),geInterpolatedDataPoint(dbName, tblName, timestamp, ids, 5w) and so on
```

The example script are as follows:

```py
def prev_next_method(rawDataTable, timestamp, ids,type,search_range=1d){
    if (type=="prev") {
        original_table = select * from rawDataTable where id in ids, time between temporalAdd(timestamp,-1H) : timestamp context by id csort time limit -1// 如果表内数据是按照时间增序，则把csort time删掉，会快很多
    }
    if (type=="next") {
        original_table = select * from rawDataTable where id in ids, time between timestamp : temporalAdd(timestamp,1H) context by id csort time limit 1    
    }
    exclude_id= (set(ids)-set(exec id from original_table)).keys()
        if (size(exclude_id) >0){
            if (type=="prev") {
                search=duration("-"+string(search_range))
                original_table_con = select * from rawDataTable where id in exclude_id , time between temporalAdd(timestamp,search) : timestamp context by exclude_id csort time limit -1
            }
            if (type=="next") {
                original_table_con = select * from rawDataTable where id in exclude_id , time between timestamp : temporalAdd(timestamp,search_range)  context by exclude_id csort time limit 1 
            }
        exclude_id_final = (set(exclude_id)-set(exec id from original_table_con)).keys()
        
        exclude_table = table(timestamp as time, exclude_id_final as id, take(double(NULL), size(exclude_id_final)) as value) 
        return original_table.append!(original_table_con).append!(exclude_table)
            }
    else return original_table
    }
def geInterpolatedDataPoint(dbName, tblName, timestamp, ids, type="prev",search_range=1d){
    tmp=table(take(timestamp, size(ids)) as time, ids as id)    
    rawDataTable = loadTable(dbName,tblName)
    if (type=="prev") {
        res_tmp= prev_next_method(rawDataTable, timestamp, ids,"prev",search_range)
        update res_tmp set time = timestamp
        return res_tmp
        }       
    if (type=="next") {
        res_tmp= prev_next_method(rawDataTable, timestamp, ids,"next",search_range)
        update res_tmp set time = timestamp
        return res_tmp
        }   
    if (type=="linear"){
        pre = prev_next_method(rawDataTable, timestamp, ids,"prev",search_range)
        nex = prev_next_method(rawDataTable, timestamp, ids,"next",search_range)
        update tmp set value = double()
        join_res=(pre.append!(tmp).append!(nex)).sortBy!(`id,1)
        res_tmp=select time, id, nullFill((time-prev(time))\(next(time)-prev(time))*(next(value)-prev(value)),0)+prev(value) as value1 from join_res context by id
        res = select timestamp as time, id, sum(value1) from res_tmp group by id
        return res      
        }
    }
```